# Need to populate JSON Array data in HTML Table

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, json

I have this HTML

```
    <div class="searchresults">
    <div class="result">
        <!-- document ISO number -->
        <h4><a class="published" href="#">ISO 105-A05:1996</a></h4>
        <!-- document title -->
        <p>
            Textiles -- Tests for colour fastness -- Part A05: Instrumental assessment of change in colour for determination of grey scale rating
        </p>
        <h2 class="toggle">More details<span></span></h2>
        <div class="more_details clearfix">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                <tr>
                    <th>Edition</th>
                    <th>Stage</th>
                    <th>TC</th>
                    <th>ICS</th>
                    <th>Document available as of</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>90.93</td>
                    <td><a href="#">ISO/TC 38/SC 1</a></td>
                    <td><a href="#">59.080.01</a></td>
                    <td>1996-03-28</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>  
    </div>  <!--result /--> 
</div>
```

If it is normal JSP i could get the list and iterate the div and fetch result like this

```
    <div class="searchresults">
    <%
    for(List lists:list) {
    %>
    <div class="result">
        <!-- document ISO number -->
        <h4><a class="published" href="#">ISO 105-A05:1996</a></h4>
        <!-- document title -->
        <p>
            Textiles -- Tests for colour fastness -- Part A05: Instrumental assessment of change in colour for determination of grey scale rating
        </p>
        <h2 class="toggle">More details<span></span></h2>
        <div class="more_details clearfix">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                <tr>
                    <th>Edition</th>
                    <th>Stage</th>
                    <th>TC</th>
                    <th>ICS</th>
                    <th>Document available as of</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>90.93</td>
                    <td><a href="#">ISO/TC 38/SC 1</a></td>
                    <td><a href="#">59.080.01</a></td>
                    <td>1996-03-28</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>  
    </div>  <!--result /--> 
    <%
     }
     %>
</div>
```

But in my case am making an ajax call and getting the JSON Array How do Iterate the div like shown above with JSON data and populate the table What should I call in onsuccess of ajax call?

Comment: Do what you would do for a JSP, except use JavaScript instead of Java?

Comment: Sir here am using an ajax call getting JSON Array How would I loop that over an div (ie: like an List)?

Comment: You have an array of objects. You have a table that needs to have the rows populated with the data in that array. Use a template for the table head and foot, and build the body by iterating the rows to populate them with data.

The best idea is to give it a shot and when you find a specific problem, like data not properly populating the row, show us what you have tried, what you expect to see, and what you actually see when the code runs.

Comment: What does your JSON data look like? That really drives how to approach the problem. In general, what The Head Rush said about doing as  you would do with JSP is correct. You'd really just loop over the collection of documents and then using a template, bind the document data to the template. Rinse and repeat until you are done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finding how to do an AJAX call is pretty easy to find on [jQuery's website](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) so I'm going to skip that. I'm also going to assume that you'll be working with JSON as your result from the server.

What you can do, is to use a templating library, and I'm going to use [handlebars.js](http://handlebarsjs.com/) for this example.

First using a special script tag take your results HTML from above and use that as your template.

```
<script id="results" type="text/x-handlebars-template"> 
 ... notice the double braces ...
       <h4><a class="published" href="#">ISO {{published}}</a></h4>
</script>
```

Replacing all of the items which are dynamic and would come from your AJAX call with handlebars' double braces.

Now you would take your AJAX result set and place that into a local array. From your page, get the html element where you will add your data.

```
  <div id="replacement"></div>
```

Now iterate over each item from your local results set and the use the item data to fill in the templated variables you setup earlier. Keep adding the templated HTML elements to a placeholder. When you're done, you can now set the created templates to the replacement element.

```
// define the source of your template and complie for use.
var source = document.getElementById('results').innerHTML;
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);

// faked AJAX results set  
var resultSet=[ {
  published: '105-A05:1996',
  title: "Textiles -- Tests for colour fastness -- Part A05:
          Instrumental assessment of change in colour for 
          determination of grey scale rating",
  Edition: '1',
  Stage: "90.93",
  TC: 'ISO/TC 38/SC 1',
  ICS: '59.080.01',
  available: '1996-03-28'
}

var appendedHtml = '';
// get the element where you will add your data.
var element = document.getElementById('replacement');    

// iterate over each entry from your data
resultSet.forEach(function(entry) {
  // the entey data now will fill in the templated variables
   var html = template(entry);
   // keep adding the html elements to a placeholder.
   appendedHtml += html
});

// now set the created templates to the replacement element.
element.innerHTML = appendedHtml;
```

Here's a [working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/MgqKkJ?p=preview) for you to check out. This should be enough to get you up and going. There are two keys to this solution, using a template library for your data replacement and iterating over the results to create many copies of the same template.

Good luck and hope this helps some.

Comment: Chris Thanks for you help it working but can I get an example of iterating an JSON array instead of using an template .

Comment: I have to call the ajax call on click of checkbox so Iam appending the code given by you in onSuccess and it doesnt work but when I give the exact code on page load it works properly and the checkbox am using is AUI which is outside the template I mean in an separate div

Comment: So you are not wanting to have your results displayed in the way you have your HTML?  You really need to show an example of your JSON so that we can get a better understanding of what you are wanting to do. From what I can tell so far, the only iteration you will need is a forEach on your JSON results which will be inserted into the templated div  you have in your question. Please provide more information if this is not correct.

Comment: Thank You soo much Chris and Head Rush for your time and efforts.Chris Ihave used and implemented like as you have suggested in working plunker using handlebars.js thank you soo much guys :)